# kotlin data class constructors not getting picked up

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I am creating a data class in kotlin as such

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
{
    constructor(name: String, age: Int, size: String): this(name, age) {
    }

}
```

In my main function, I can access the objects as such:

```
fun main(){

    val x = User("foo", 5, "M")
    println(x.name)
    println(x.age)
    println(x.size) // does not work
}
```

My problem is that I can't get access to `size`.

What I am trying to do is, create a `data class` where top level params are the common items that will be accessed, and in the constructors, have additional params that fit certain situations. The purpose is so that I can do something like

```
// something along the lines of 
if (!haveSize()){
    val person = User("foo", 5, "M")
} else {
     val person = User("foo", 5)
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `size` is not a property of `User`, it's simply a constructor parameter. It does not exist outside of the constructor, hence you can't access it as you would if it was a property. Should it be a property?

Comment: Can you not achieve your goal with default parameter values? For example: data class User(val name: String, val age: Int, val size: String? = null )

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response - but i realize my question and code was not accurately describing my problem statement. i've edited it. could you please take a look?

Comment: Can you not achieve your goal with default parameter values? For example: data class User(val name: String, val detailsOne: OneDetails? = null, val detailsTwo: TwoDetails? = null ) ? You could then say something like: "1" -> anotherCaller(User(mt, detailsOne  = one))

Comment: no i cannot. because `OneDetails` and `TwoDetails` will have different kinds of values being passed in. so i guess i'm looking to see if its possible to do `overloading` on the data class.

Comment: Very odd, what error do you get?

Comment: Hi @jakewong, I just rolled back your question to a previous version, since there were already multiple answers under the question and the recent edit changed the question completely. Please create a new question with the updated description if you don't see an answer here yet.

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin you do not need separate constructors for defining optional constructor params. You can define them all in a single constructor with default values or make them nullable, like this:

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int, val size: String = "M")
```

```
fun main(){
    val x = User("foo", 5, "L")
    val y = User("foo", 5)

    println(x.size) // "L" from call site
    println(y.size) // "M" from default param
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response - but i realize my question and code was not accurately describing my problem statement. i've edited it. could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You can not access size variable, because this is from secondary construct, but we have alternative variant.

```
data class User(var name: String, var age: Int) {

 var size: String

 init {
     size = "size"
  }

constructor(name: String, age: Int, size: String) : this(name, age) {
    this.size = size
  }
}
```

Comment: this would be a more than appropriate Java answer, but in Kotlin it would be much more advisable to make use of optional parameters instead of creating multiple constructors.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response - but i realize my question and code was not accurately describing my problem statement. i've edited it. could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you want to have one property that can be one of a limited number of options. This could be solved using [generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html), or [sealed inheritance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html).

##### Generics

Here I've added an interface, `MountDetails`, with a generic parameter, `T`. There's a single property, `val c`, which is of type `T`.

```kotlin
data class User(
    val mountOptions: MountOptions,
    val mountDetails: MountDetails<*>,
)

data class MountOptions(
    val a: String,
    val b: String
)

interface MountDetails<T : Any> {
    val c: T
}

data class MountOneDetails(override val c: Int) : MountDetails<Int>

data class MountTwoDetails(override val c: String) : MountDetails<String>
```

Because the implementations `MountDetails` (`MountOneDetails` and `MountTwoDetails`) specify the type of `T` to be `Int` or `String`, `val c` can always be accessed.

```kotlin
fun anotherCaller(user: User) {
    println(user.mountOptions.a)
    println(user.mountOptions.b)

    println(user.mountDetails)
}

fun main() {
    val mt = MountOptions("foo", "bar")

    val mountOneDetails = MountOneDetails(111)
    anotherCaller(User(mt, mountOneDetails))

    val mountTwoDetails = MountTwoDetails("mount two")
    anotherCaller(User(mt, mountTwoDetails))
}
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
MountOneDetails(c=111)
foo
bar
MountTwoDetails(c=mount two)
```

Generics have downsides though. If there are lots of generic parameters it's messy, and it can be difficult at runtime to determine the type of classes thanks to type-erasure.

##### Sealed inheritance

Since you only have a limited number of mount details, a much neater solution is [sealed classes and interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html).

```kotlin
data class User(val mountOptions: MountOptions)

sealed interface MountOptions {
    val a: String
    val b: String
}

data class MountOneOptions(
    override val a: String,
    override val b: String,
    val integerData: Int,
) : MountOptions

data class MountTwoOptions(
    override val a: String,
    override val b: String,
    val stringData: String,
) : MountOptions
```

The benefit here is that there's fewer classes, and the typings are more specific. It's also easy to add or remove an additional mount details, and any [exhaustive `when` statements](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) will cause a compiler error.

```kotlin
fun anotherCaller(user: User) {
    println(user.mountOptions.a)
    println(user.mountOptions.b)

    // use an exhaustive when to determine the actual type
    when (user.mountOptions) {
        is MountOneOptions -> println(user.mountOptions.integerData)
        is MountTwoOptions -> println(user.mountOptions.stringData)
        // no need for an 'else' branch
    }
}

fun main() {

    val mountOne = MountOneOptions("foo", "bar", 111)
    anotherCaller(User(mountOne))

    val mountTwo = MountTwoOptions("foo", "bar", "mount two")
    anotherCaller(User(mountTwo))
}
```

Output:

```
foo
bar
111
foo
bar
mount two
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really the "default values" answer provided by Hubert Grzeskowiak adjusted to your example:

```kotlin
data class OneDetails(val c: Int)
data class TwoDetails(val c: String)
data class MountOptions(val a: String, val b: String)

data class User(
    val mountOptions: MountOptions,
    val detailsOne: OneDetails? = null,
    val detailsTwo: TwoDetails? = null
)

fun main() {
    fun anotherCaller(user: User) = println(user)
    
    val mt = MountOptions("foo", "bar")
    val one = OneDetails(1)
    val two = TwoDetails("2")

    val switch = "0"
    when (switch) {
        "0" -> anotherCaller(User(mt))
        "1" -> anotherCaller(User(mt, detailsOne = one))
        "2" -> anotherCaller(User(mt, detailsTwo = two))
        "12" -> anotherCaller(User(mt, detailsOne = one, detailsTwo = two))
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException(switch)
    }
}
```